# Selenium 3.4.0, FF -53.02 getting org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset only on firefox browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, selenium3

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'

Comment: Please add more information about your test set up? What is your Selenium version? and your code snippet for the same.

Comment: @NaveenM Can you consider showing us your work please? Thanks

Comment: Selenium Version3.4.0, FF version is: 53.0.3 Gecko driver v0.16.1

Comment: Still getting the java.net.SocketException inconstantly 
2017-05-23 10:04:48,920 ERROR [main] (AdhocReportGroupTabPage.java:202) - Failed to select Order By value org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'XXXN430', ip: '192.XX.XX.XX', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Comment: Check version compatibilty... it seems that your current firefox version is not supporting. Try lower firefox version

Comment: I am using the same version, not sure how but issue got resolved by itself.

Comment: Any one able to solve this issue ?